# ml5.js Error: Error when checking : expected dense_Dense1_input to have shape [null,250] but got array with shape [1,1]

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a model with ml5.js and I get an error in the console  saying:
`Error: Error when checking : expected dense_Dense1_input to have shape [null,250] but got array with shape [1,1].`

**With this command you can copy all the project files to your computer to test it:**

`git clone https://github.com/anonym2048/mystuff.git`

**sketch.js**

```
var options = {
     task: "regression",
     debug: true,
     dataUrl: "germany_covid.csv",
     inputs: ["Date"],
     outputs: ["Cases"],
     layers: [
          {
               type: 'dense',
               units: 16,
               inputShape: [250], //what should I put here?
               activation: 'relu',
          },
          {
               type: 'dense',
               activation: 'sigmoid',
          },
     ],
};
     
var nn = ml5.neuralNetwork(options, train);

function train() {
     nn.normalizeData();
     
     var trainingOptions = {
          epochs: 256,
          batchSize: 500,
     };
     
     nn.train(trainingOptions, predict);
}

function predict(){
     nn.predict({"Date": "2020-10-20"}).then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
     });
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" >
     <title></title>
</head>

<body>


     <script src="ml5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The csv file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anonym2048/mystuff/main/germany_covid.csv

I expect it to give me a prediction result in the console.

I tried to play around with the "inputShape" property of the object but when I changed the value from 250 to let's say [1,1], then the training of the model didn't start.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that input values must be numbers. I used strings.